# Effect of `modes` In Declare Form

Tags: completion, commands, declare

[13.14 The `declare` Form](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Declare-Form.html):

> `(modes MODES)`
>
> Specify that this command is meant to be applicable for MODES only.

What is the practical effect of `(modes ...)` in *declare form*?

---

I find that I can still call function `shyn/func`:

```lisp
(defun shyn/func ()
  (declare (modes text-mode))
  (interactive))
```

in any mode other than *text-mode*.

---

###### Update 2023-6-15

Reported as [bug#64045](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=64045); Related documentation got clarified.

Comment: I suspect that this advisory only: it is not enforced by anybody.

Comment: @NickD: I remember there seems to be an *option* that determines whether or not to ignore *command*s that are not applicable to the currently active modes when completing commands. But I forgot what it was (and if it exists, I should have turned it on ).

Comment: Are you thinking of [this](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Command-Modes.html) perhaps?

Comment: @NickD: Exactly! So, it's not just an advisory, is it? Perhaps you can formulate an answer based on this.

Comment: n.b. That's new in Emacs 28.  See "Lisp Changes in Emacs 28.1" in the NEWS file.