# `completion` In Declare Form Not Working

Tags: completion, commands, declare

Why is this function:

```lisp
(defun shyn/func ()
  (declare (completion (lambda (symbol current-buffer)
                         nil)))
  (interactive))
```

still listed by pressing `M-x TAB` in buffer `*scratch*`?

---

[13.14 The `declare` Form](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Declare-Form.html#index-declare-1):

> `(completion COMPLETION-PREDICATE)`
>
> Declare COMPLETION-PREDICATE as a function to determine whether to include the symbol in the list of functions when asking for completions in `M-x`.

---

###### Update 2023-6-15

Reported as [bug#64045](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=64045); Related documentation got clarified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Perhaps a documentation bug.**

As I quoted from the [*manual*](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/index.html), the `completion` clause indeed has that feature as stated.  
However, whether this feature is enabled is related to the value of the *option* **`read-extended-command-predicate`**, which the [*manual*](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/index.html) doesn't mention (at least not in the context of the [quoted text](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Declare-Form.html#index-declare-1)).

(Thanks to [@NickD](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users/14825) for providing [relevant and useful information](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/77597/effect-of-modes-in-declare-form#comment129157_77597).)

For instance, you can enable it like this:

```lisp
(setq read-extended-command-predicate #'command-completion-default-include-p)
```

Comment: Can you submit a documentation bug?

Comment: @NickD: Will do.